# How can I avoid interactive text UI stage during package installation?

Tags: shell-script, interactive

The krb5-user package install on Ubuntu requires the installer to interact with a text UI screen that comes up asking about Kerberos. I'm trying to automate installation and this is one of the points thats forcing interaction.

[image]

No input is needed for my purposes.

Can a magic shell command somehow press OK in this text UI for me?

Comment: -1 with no comment. What can I do to improve this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using following apt-get with following options in scripts to tell both apt and dpkg to not ask for confirmation and other options, it should work here too:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef" -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold" install <package>
```